# Should I be required to award a bounty if there has been no activity since I offered it?

Tags: discussion, bounties

For reasons that completely agree with (avoiding bounty gaming, free attention, and so forth) bounties are not refundable (barring moderator intervention).

However, sometimes I offer a bounty and there is no activity on the question between the time the bounty is offered and the time it is awarded.

If I offer a bounty, and

- there are no new answers, and
- none of the current answers have been edited

why should it be awarded to anybody? In this situation, it is a waste of my reputation and an unmerited award to one of the answerers.

Also, when this occurs, should I flag it and ask a moderator to remove the bounty?

Comment: *"why should it be awarded to anybody"* and *"it is a waste of my reputation"* are unrelated. (And both are false, I feel.)

Comment: AFAIK a bounty will only be auto-awarded to upvoted new answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why should it be awarded to anybody?

If there hasn't been any activity during the bounty, it *won't* be awarded to anyone. You are never required to award the bounty, and automatic awarding only occurs under certain circumstances.

> Should I flag it and ask a moderator to remove the bounty?

Not unless you want a declined flag. Your bounty is advertising, and there's no guarantee that it will actually generate activity or new answers. You cannot request removal of it just because you didn't get the results you wanted. A moderator will just let it expire.

Comment: Oh, I thought the bounty would always be automatically awarded regardless of the activity. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're under the impression that bounties are *always* awarded to one of the answers. **It is not**.

**Some important points to note:**

- If you didn't get any answers during the bounty period, the bounty will not be awarded to anyone
- If you did receive some answers, and you didn't manually award the bounty to any answer during the bounty period, then the bounty may be awarded automatically
- If you accepted an answer during the bounty period, then the bounty will be automatically awarded to that answer
- If you did not accept an answer, the highest scoring answer will be awarded **half** the bounty amount

If none of these conditions are met, the bounty is **not awarded** to anyone.

For more details,  refer to this FAQ entry: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)